# jQuery $.method() vs $(selector).method()

Tags: jquery

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between `$.method()` and `$(selector).method` for jQuery.

What elements in the DOM does the `$.method()` actually apply for? If anyone could help explain the difference between the two statements, it would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

A `$()` requires a selector to grab the element and return that into a chain. While `$.` is an ordinary method that can be used that isn't chained of the DOM element.

Take this for example:

```
// Will trim the current string - returns string
$.trim(' string ')

// Returns the current element in the DOM ready for chaining, i.e. $().remove
$('#id')
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods assigned to the jQuery object directly don't apply to any collection: they're utility methods (that's why they're assigned there).

For example, look at `$.each()` and `$.noConflict()`.

Answer (score 1):

`$.function()` are helper functions that you can use however you like. Some of these are obsolete since a lot have been added to the object prototypes (e.g. `Array.forEach()`), like `$.each()`. The official [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) describes `$.each()` as

> Description: A generic iterator function, which can be used to
>   seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like
>   objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object)
>   are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are
>   iterated via their named properties.

while `.each()` iterates over a jQuery object and executes the callback on every matched element.

In a nutshell: functions that apply to jQuery objects work on/with those while the others are helper functions.

Answer (score -1):

The one liner is, `either you want to get the input also for you and apply method on it or you have input and want to apply jQuery method on it`. This question is very broad.